# Display JSON data based on initial value selected

Tags: ios, json, swift, segue, swifty-json

I have a JSON file (currently local, but will be a URL in time) containing terms, descriptions, and ids. What I'm trying to achieve is to list all of the terms in my initial view, and then depending on what is selected, show a new view (via segue) with the term + it's associated description showing.

In my initial view controller I have a TableView currently displaying the list of terms from the JSON. I've managed to pass through the selected term through to the new view, but I'm struggling with displaying the associated description. I'm using SwiftyJSON and my parser looks like:

```
func parseJSON(){
    let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("scrumTerms", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    NumberofRows = readableJSON["Terms"].count

    for i in 1...NumberofRows{
        var item = "item"
        item += "\(i)"
        let term = readableJSON["Terms"][item]["term"].string as String!
        let description = readableJSON["Terms"][item]["description"].string as String!
        let id = readableJSON["Terms"][item]["id"].int as Int!


        TermsArray.append(term)
        DescriptionArray.append(description)
        //IdArray.append(id)
    }
```

Displaying the initial list looks like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

    if TermsArray.count != 0{
        cell.textLabel?.text = TermsArray[indexPath.row]

    }

    return cell
}
```

And then my segue section looks like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    viewTerm = currentCell.textLabel!.text

    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewTerm", sender: self)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if (segue.identifier == "viewTerm") {

        // define new view controller
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! viewTermController
        // define the new view controller property that will store the passed value(s)
        viewController.viewTerm = viewTerm
        viewController.viewDescription = "THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO GET TO"
    }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of building two arrays, why not make a dictionary with the term as key and the description as value? Then you can set the term like you do now (`viewController.viewTerm = viewTerm`) and the description as `viewController.viewDescription = termDict[viewTerm]`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl - many thanks! I've re-worked the entire section to create a dictionary and make use of the 'key, value' parameters. I'm new to (swift) development so it took a while to achieve but it's working great! Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented successfully using an alternate approach (dictionary) as per initial comment from Michael, as well as using SwitfyJSON. Thanks.

I ended up declaring my JSON as:

```
 let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MY FILE NAME", ofType: "json") as String!
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!

    let json = JSON(data: data)

    parseJSON(json)
```

Then the parse function looked like:

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for result in json["results"].arrayValue {
        let title = result["keyTerm"].stringValue
        let desc = result["description"].stringValue
        let termId = result["termId"].stringValue
        let obj = ["keyTerm": title, "description": desc, "termId": termId]

        objects.append(obj)   
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then my segue that passes the selected row's values through to the 2nd view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row]
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object   
        }
    }
}
```